# in libjvm.so wrong ELF class ELFCLASS64

Tags: linux, centos

I have installed java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.65-2.5.1.2.el6_5.x86_64 on Cent OS 6.6. When i am trying to run my software it is thorwing error in "libjvm.so wrong ELF class ELFCLASS64". while I ran java -version output is-->

```
java version 1.7.0_15
java SE runtime environment (build 1.7.0_15)
Java Hotspot 64Bit Server VM (build 23.7-b01, mixed mode)

JRE version on machine
Jre – 1.7.0_15-fcs.x86_84
JDK version
java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.65-2.5.1.2.el6_5.x86_64
```

Comment: What is your software doing when it's throwing this error ? What is the exact command line being run and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Your software is a 32-bit ELF file but `libjvm.so` is only available as a 64-bit ELF library. The runtime linker therefor cannot link the library.

You either need to compile your program in 64-bit mode or get a 32-bit JVM.